# Django can't find a specific static file

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm getting a 404 when trying to load 'irpf.jpg' which is in the same folder as 'jumbotron.jpg'. Other files are served normally as well, just the 'irpf' can't be found at all. Tried to run collectstatic but it says that no changes where detected.
Any ideas?
Thanks,

The first one loads, the second don't
[static files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0M3L.jpg)

```
<div class="col">
<img src="{% static 'appStaticSite/jumbotron.jpg' %}" alt="Imposto de Renda">
<img src="{% static 'appStaticSite/irpf.jpg' %}" alt="Imposto de Renda">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the jumbotron got displayed correctly?

Comment: Are you certain about the file name? No leading/trailing spaces, no homoglyphs?

Comment: Yes, the jumbotron works fine and the filename is correct. Actually I get this error on my local (development) server. I tested on the live server now and it works... quite odd.